# Releasing focus from a twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, focus, blur

I have a NavBar in Twitter Bootstrap with links that open Modals.
Below I have a Canvas where different items are dragged.

The issue I have is that on some mobile devices, whenever I open the NavBar and I open a Modal from one of its links and I click on the content of the modal, and then close it all, the focus somehow get's transferred to that modal, and the dragging below the Navbar becomes really slow. The way to reset it that I found is doing a simple Tap on the Navbar, then all goes back to normal. But obviously I need to find a way programmatically to release the focus without having to ask the user to tap the Navbar.

The problem does not happen if you simply open and close the dropdowns in the navbar, or if you open a modal and close it without clicking inside of it.
For the problem to happen one has to click inside the content of the modal. I guess that's what sets the Focus to the modal. And then the problem happens. I close the modal and close the dropdown and all, and yet somehow the focus stays somewhere there because the rest of the app gets into trouble until i tap on the Navbar which seems to release the focus and all works fine again.

So how can I ensure that I fully release the focus on any modal/dropdown I have been manipulating. As you can imagine I have been trying all sorts of combinations with Blur, etc including:

```
    document.activeElement.blur();
    $("input").blur();
    $(".navbar-toggle").blur();             
    $(".navbar").blur();    
    $(".navbar-default").blur();    
    $(".collapse").blur();  
    $("#myModalHow").blur();
    $(".modal-dialog").blur();
    $(".modal-content").blur();
    $(".modal-header").blur();
    $(".modal-title").blur();
    $(".modal").blur();
    $(".close").blur();
```

etc etc

also tried to set and remove focus on another element

```
    $("#anotherelement").focus();
    $("#anotherelement").blur();
```

also tried to simulate the click on the navbar programmatically

```
    $( "#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" ).trigger( "click" );
```

no luck so far.

Comment: I just found out the following,
If i remove FADE from the modal declaration, therefore using class="modal" , instead of "modal fade",
then this lines solve the problem

        $(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            document.activeElement.blur();
However if i use FADE to fade the modal then it fails,
how can i make sure that the same solution works with FADE present?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an issue in Bootstrap with the `hidden.bs.popover` event because it is triggered before the animation ends.
You could try using `setTimeout()` to workaround this issue:

```
$(".modal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.activeElement.blur();
    }, 150);
});
```